# Detect unstable trend (timeseries)

Tags: c#, time-series, iot

I'm looking for a way to detect faulty sensors in an IOT environment.

[image: Faulty sensor]

In this case a tank level sensor. The readings are always fluctuating somewhat, and the "hop" at the beginning is a tank refill which is "normal". On Sep 16  the sensor started to malfunction and just gives apparent random values after that.

As a programmer ideally I'd like a simple way of detecting the problem (and as soon after it starts as possible).

I can mess about with "if direction of vector between two hourly averages changes direction more than once per day it is unstable". But I guess there are more sound and stable algorithms out there.

Answer (score 1):

Two simple options:

- domain knowledge based: If you know the max possible output of the tank (say 5 liter/h), any output above that would signal an error. I.e. in case of the example, if

  ```
  t1-t2 > 5
  ```

  assuming t1 and t2 show the tank capacity at hourly intervall. You might want to add sensor accuracy related safety margin.
- past data based: Assuming that all tanks are similar regarding output capacity and used sensor quality, calculate the following for all your data of non-faulty sensors:

  ```
  max(t1-t2)
  ```

  The result is the error threshold to be used, similar to the value 5 above.

Note: tank refill operation might require additional consideration.

Additional methods are described e.g. here. You can find other papers for sure.
http://bourbon.usc.edu/leana/pubs-full/sensorfaults.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Standard deviation.

You're looking at how much variation there is between the measurements. Standard deviation is an easy formula, and well known. Look for a high value, and you know there's a problem.

You can also use coefficient of variation, which is the ratio of the mean to standard deviation.